# What is exactly Ruby's `not` keyword?

Tags: ruby, grammar

[The documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#not) claims that `not` is just another spelling of `!` (supposedly with different precedence).

[The parser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cb029fa4e8d2e8778f7a7b911bc7f0a0bd675524/parse.y#L3331) says that

```
expr        : command_call
                | keyword_not '\n'? expr
                    {
                        $$ = call_uni_op(p, method_cond(p, $3, &@3), METHOD_NOT, &@1, &@$);
                    /*% ripper: unary!(ID2VAL(idNOT), $:3) %*/
                    }
```

but not all expressions are valid.  It pretty much requires parens.  Is this really wanted?

```
irb> x = !true
=> false

irb> not true
=> false

irb> x = !true
=> false

irb> x = not true
/Users/akim/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/irb-1.12.0/lib/irb/workspace.rb:117:in `eval': (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected `true', expecting '(' (SyntaxError)
x = not true
        ^~~~

    from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
    from /Users/akim/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/irb-1.12.0/exe/irb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/local/bin/irb:25:in `load'
    from /opt/local/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'

irb> x = not(true)
=> false

irb> x = (not true)
=> false
```

(IRB's behavior matches exactly that of MRI.)

Comment: How about `= (not true)`?

Comment: Due to operator precedence, `x = not true` is parsed as `x = not` followed by a seemingly stray `true`.

Comment: @akim my point is that since the precedence must be resolved, writing `(not true)` is far more natural looking solution than you `not(true)`. So there really is no question to answer here.

Comment: @Stefan I really don't see how precedence can explain such a behavior here.  Appears too late to change the behavior of the assignment.

Comment: @matt My question is really not about how to workaround this, I know how, and actually I simply never use `not`.  My question is rather what the heck is going on here.

Comment: "What the heck is going on here" is rather vague.

Comment: `!` has extremely high precedence, while `not` has one of the lowest, well below `=`. This means the evaluation order is completely different, as Stefan points out.

Comment: What is going on here is exactly as described by other commenters. **Precedence**. As stated by @Stefan the parser views this expression `x = not true` as `(x =not) true` because assignment `=` has a higher precedence than `not`. `x = not` is syntactically invalid and thus raises an error.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is this really wanted?

Yes and no, it depends on the use case. For assignments, `not`'s low [precedence](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) isn't really useful because it requires parentheses due to the assignment operator.

When combined with `if` however, its low precedence allows to omit parentheses:

```
if not a == b
  # do something
end
```

as opposed to `!` which has the highest precedence and therefore requires parentheses:

```
if !(a == b)
  # do something
end
```

(you could also use `unless` here, but sometimes `if not` is more explicit / easier to read)